# terraform variable type for list of maps

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Creating a terraform code for aws secrets creation and I am not sure which variable type I should use.

Which variable type should I use in this example?

main.tf contains this to feed

```
data "vault_generic_secret" "aws_secrets" {
  for_each = var.aws_secrets

  path = each.value.vault_path
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "aws_secrets" {
  for_each      = var.aws_secrets
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.aws_secrets.id
  secret_string = jsonencode(data.vault_generic_secret.aws_secrets[each.value.vault_field])
}
```

```
aws_secrets = [
  {
    aws_secret_id = "foo"
    vault_path    = "/path1"
    vault_field   = "foo"
  },
  {  
    aws_secret_id = "bar"
    vault_path    = "/path2"
    vault_field   = "bar"
  }
]
```

which should be right for variables.tf?

this

```
variable "aws_secrets" {
  type = list(
    object({
      aws_secret_id = string,
      vault_path    = string,
      vault_field   = string,
    })
  )
  default = []
}
```

With this, I get this error

`The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type list of object.`

or

with this

```
aws_secrets = {
  object = {
    aws_secret_id = "foo"
    vault_path    = "/path1"
    vault_field   = "foo"
  },
  {  
    aws_secret_id = "bar"
    vault_path    = "/path2"
    vault_field   = "bar"
  }
}
```

```
variable "aws_secrets" {
  type = map(
    object({
      aws_secret_id = string,
      vault_path    = string,
      vault_field   = string,
    })
  )
  default = {}
}
```

This seems better, but I get another issue that I can't explain exactly here. I want to clarify which variable type before progressing further in either direction.

Comment: Please run your code, and tell us which one works.

Comment: Both are not working for another incomplete part in the code. I was hoping to confirm which variable type first with the example.

Comment: The error is about `for_each` yet you haven't showed the code with `for_each` which produces the error.

Comment: Ok, so the type `list` or `map` doesn't matter?

Comment: It matters, as for_each works only with maps, but its easy to convert map to list. But off course you haven't showed your code producing the error, so its difficult to speculate how you are using for_each.

Comment: ok, got it, I added more codes to my post.
the latest error I see when using `maps` type is `Error: Invalid index. The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your list of maps, to a map of maps as follows:

```
 for_each = {for idx, val in var.aws_secrets: idx => val}
```

otherwise change your variable to a map of maps:

```
aws_secrets = {
  "foo" = {
    aws_secret_id = "foo"
    vault_path    = "/path1"
    vault_field   = "foo"
  },
  "bar" = {  
    aws_secret_id = "bar"
    vault_path    = "/path2"
    vault_field   = "bar"
  }
}
```